# How can I assign a variable the largest 32 bit signed value in ruby without explicitly defining it

Tags: ruby, integer, bignum, fixnum

I want to be able to assign a variable the number 2147483647, the maximum 32-bit signed integer value. Is there some way that I can retrieve a value from the class, such as Integer::MAX?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why do you want to do this? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There is no maximum integer in Ruby.

Comment: `class Integer; MAX = 2147483647; end` if you need it in the base class, but [I don't recommend](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/) monkey patching base classes. Just put it in one of your own classes.

Comment: You can easily calculate the value: `MAX_INT = (1 << 31) - 1`

Answer (score 7):

In CRuby 2.5 and newer you can do the following:

```
require 'rbconfig/sizeof'
RbConfig::LIMITS['INT32_MAX']  # => 2147483647
```

The keys of `RbConfig::LIMITS` are the names of C limit macros (see `<limits.h>`, `<stdint.h>` and `<float.h>`) except `FIXNUM_*` which is a Ruby implementation detail.

I recommend defining your own constant (or local variable) for these limits though. It's more portable.